# Swap even/odd characters

Tags: strings, programming-challenge, functional-programming, f#

I wrote some code to solve this problem https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/string-o-permute which basically states: take an even length string and swap all the even indexed characters. For example the string "abcd" should become "badc". I'm looking for a general code review as I'm very new to F# and specifically I'd really like to get rid of the ignoredTupleValue variable, it seems like a kludge to me. I'd also like to collapse the whole thing into one function but I was running into scoping issues with the StringBuilder.

```
open System
open System.Text

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let numCases = Console.ReadLine() |> int
    for i = numCases downto 1 do
        let strIn = Console.ReadLine()
        let pairs = Seq.pairwise strIn
        let ignoredTupleValue = ('1', '1')
        let swappedTuples = pairs |> Seq.mapi (fun idx pair ->
                                if idx % 2 = 0 then
                                    let (a, b) = pair
                                    (b, a)
                                else
                                    ignoredTupleValue)
        let answer = Seq.fold (fun (sb : StringBuilder) pair ->
                                if pair <> ignoredTupleValue then
                                    let (a, b) = pair
                                    sb.Append(a) |> ignore
                                    sb.Append(b) |> ignore
                                sb)
                                (new StringBuilder())
                                swappedTuples
        printfn "%s" (answer.ToString())
    0
```

Comment: There are many ways to do this problem, but if you're interested in removing `ignoredTupleValue `, think about using Seq.filter(...)

Comment: I changed the title to describe the task the code accomplishes, this makes contrnt morr easily searchable and accesible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building off Caridorc's pseudocode, this function would do it:

```
let switchOddAndEven (str : string) =
    str.ToCharArray()
    |> Array.chunkBySize 2
    |> Array.map Array.rev
    |> Array.concat
    |> System.String.Concat
```

The first and last methods are just switching between a `char` array and a `string`. Usage is simply:

```
switchOddAndEven "abcd";;
// val it : string = "badc"
```

or in your `main` method

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let numCases = Console.ReadLine() |> int
    for i = numCases downto 1 do
        Console.ReadLine()
        |> switchOddAndEven
        |> printfn "%s"
    0
```

Note you don't need a full blown console app to do these kind of things. Create a new `fsx` file in Visual Studio (File -> New -> File -> F# Script File) then type your functions there. To execute just select it all and send it to the F# Interactive with `Alt + Enter`.

Edit

From the comments: one could take advantage of the fact that `string` is an `IEnumerable` and use the `Seq` module, which saves one method call:

```
let switchOddAndEven (str : string) = 
    str 
    |> Seq.chunkBySize 2 
    |> Seq.map Seq.rev 
    |> Seq.concat 
    |> System.String.Concat
```

Comment: I'll give you the bounty if you change the name of the function to something descriptive, I hate names with "my" in them

Comment: Heh. Changed it. What's in a name.

Comment: Everything is in a name :)

Comment: Good that F# has all the necessary built-ins including chunks_of . I just think that strings should be a kind a list (strings `subset_of` lists) to avoid this back & forth conversion, but the designers of the language chose them to be different and there is no going back.

Comment: @Caridorc that's likely more of a side effect of being built on top of the CLR more than a decision made by the F# team.

Comment: @Caridorc a string is also a sequence of chars. So instead of transforming it to an array one could use sequence operations. However, you need the same number of lines: `let switchOddAndEven (str : string) = str |> Seq.chunkBySize 2 |> Seq.map Seq.rev |> Seq.concat |> System.String.Concat`

Answer (score 7):

The solution should look like (pseudocode, I know little F# too ;) ):

```
String
  |> ChunksOf 2
  |> Map Reverse
  |> Flatten
```

An example explains clearly

```
"abcd" -> ["ab", "cd"] -> ["ba", "dc"] -> "badc"
```

The key of effective Functional Programming is making good use of the built-in functions and carefully combining them.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not very good at F#, but anytime I see a `for` or a `do` (i.e. a loop) I cringe a little bit. It's more idiomatic to use [Seq.Map](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.map%5B't,'u%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) to apply a function to each element of the range `[numCases..1]`.  Which, [since it's descending, you need to apply the step:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377083/fsharp-range-evaluation) `[numCases..-1..1]`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Printf.bprintf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/printf.bprintf%5b%27t%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d) to easily use a StringBuilder.

You could also use pattern matching to extract your length 2 array easily
*(it'll cost you a warning for not handling every case but you [as a developer] know for sure it'll have a length of 2 because of the `chunkBySize`)*

```
#nowarn "25" // to not see the aforementioned warning

let permuteEvenOdd str =
  let builder = StringBuilder (String.length str)
  let bprint format = Printf.bprintf builder format // helper to ease readability

  str
  |> Seq.chunkBySize 2
  |> Seq.iter (fun [| c1; c2 |] -> bprintf "%c%c" c2 c1)

  string builder
```

### Edit

As another alternative you can use **Seq.permute**
*(as it's documentation is not yet available I give [List.permute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.permute%5B't%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) documentation instead, the behaviour is the same)*

```
let permuteEvenOdd str =
  str
  |> Seq.permute (fun index -> index + if index % 2 = 0 then 1 else -1)
  // |> Seq.permute (fun index -> -2 * (index % 2) + 1) // alternate version ; harder to understand
  |> Seq.fold (sprintf "%s%c") "" // we could reuse bprintf here instead
```